# php calling navigation menu

Tags: php, navigation

I am trying to move my navigation bar into an external php file. So far I have moved it over and names it "navigation.php" and saved it in my root directory.

When i try to call the navigation with my html page nothing appears?

```
<?php include("navigation.php");?>
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Change the name of your index.html file to index.php. Your index file actually is interpreted as HTML, not as PHP.

Comment: +1. Alternatively, it is possible to configure the server to parse HTML files as PHP.

Comment: would this be the correct way to parse HTMl files as PHP? http://www.desilva.biz/php/phpinhtml.html

Comment: Do _not_ parse html as php if you can avoid it. It's a slippery slope that leads to all kinds of problems.

Answer (score 0):

is any other php code in your html page executed? if you just echo something, is it shown?

Comment: yeah, but you should try echo something instead of including the file. it's just for making sure that php code can be executed. if for example your html page has the ending htm than you could try changing it to .php

Comment: I've checked the server and php can be used

Comment: could you give us the piece of code, where the line is executed. maybe 3 or 4 lines before and afterwards

Comment: sure, my website it www.therisingsuntarporley.co.uk the navigation bar should show underneath the logo

Comment: Ive tried to follow these tips but seem to have got lost http://rpardz.com/blog/using-php-includes-global-navigation-links/

Comment: as i can see in the source code the php block isn't executed. otherwise i wouldn't see the line. =)
so try to rename the file to index.php

Comment: if I rename the file to index.php will I need to rename where ive reference index.html throughout my site? Thanks for your help!

Comment: yes you have. but before you do this just try renaming it to see if it is the problem. you can change the references later ;)